# c- lapack undefined reference

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, undefined-reference, lapack

I write a c code to run SVD algorithm using lapack:

test.c:

```
#include <cblas.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NX 3
#define NY 4

void
t_svd(double *x, double *y, int nx, int ny)
{
  int i;
  int nsv = (nx<ny)?nx:ny;
  int lda = ny;

  double *u = (double*)malloc(ny*ny*sizeof(double));
  double *vt = (double*)malloc(nx*nx*sizeof(double));
  double *s = (double*)malloc(nsv*sizeof(double));

  // Workspace and status variables:
  double workSize;
  double *work = &workSize;
  int lwork = -1;
  int *iwork = malloc(8*nsv*sizeof(int));
  int info = 0;

  dgesdd_("A",&ny,&nx,x,&lda,s,u,&ny,vt,&nx,work,&lwork,iwork,&info);

  // Optimal workspace size is returned in work[0].
  lwork = workSize;
  work = malloc(lwork*sizeof(double));

  // Call dgesdd_ to do the actual computation:
  dgesdd_("A",&ny,&nx,x,&lda,s,u,&ny,vt,&nx,work,&lwork,iwork,&info);
  if (info != 0){
    exit(1);
  }
  // Cleanup workspace:
  free(work);
  free(iwork);
  cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,ny,nx,nsv,1,u,ny,vt,nx,0,y,ny);

  free(u);
  free(s);
  free(vt);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double in_array[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1,
                        1, 1, 1, 1,
                        1, 1, 1, 1};
  double *out_array;

  out_array = (double*)malloc(NX*NY*sizeof(double));

  t_svd(in_array, out_array, NX, NY);
  free(out_array);
}
```

makefile:

```
test: test.c
    gcc -o test test.c -llapack -lblas
```

I run make and I got:

```
gcc -o test test.c -llapack -lblas 
//usr/lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write@GFORTRAN_1.4'
//usr/lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write@GFORTRAN_1.4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Then I tried to look at the dependency by running:

```
ldd /usr/lib/liblapack.so
```

and got:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdec307000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f8b253ff000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f8b250e5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8b24ddf000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8b24bc9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8b24804000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8b245e6000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f8b243aa000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8b26167000)
```

I tried to make my function t_svd a .so file, and the output of ldd is:

```
./libMAT.so: /soft/gcc-4.5.2/ubuntuamd1/lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3)
./libMAT.so: /soft/gcc-4.5.2/ubuntuamd1/lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/libblas.so.3)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe4328d000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /soft/gcc-4.5.2/ubuntuamd1/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fcfcdd66000)
liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 (0x00007fcfcd5ca000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007fcfccffe000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcfcccf8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcfcc933000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /soft/gcc-4.5.2/ubuntuamd1/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcfcc71e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcfcc500000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcfce24d000)
```

It seems that my libMAT.so links another libgfortran.so. What should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: have you tried `gcc -o test test.c -llapack -lblas -lgfortran`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to add -lgfortran and I still got the same problem..